# Umbraco Page types programmatically(Just like in Episerver)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, umbraco, episerver

I just started out with Umbraco for my own projects because it is cheap in comparison to Episerver. Coming from the Episerver paradigm of strongly typed Page/block types and doing everything programmatically, i now find it hard to get into Umbraco in the way i hoped to.

I know how to create simple applications but i was hoping to define my Page Types like classes with properties that Umbraco then treats as Pages. My goal is to be able to create a hierarchy of page types where certain pages inherits properties from its parent page etc.

If I have a `ArticleListingPage` I want to inside of it's controller list all types of article pages. For example if I have a `ArticleBasePage` with the properties `MainBody`, `Heading`, `Introduction` then I want these to be inherited by `ArticlePage` and `ArticleLongReadPage`. Whenever I want to list these I want to search for pages of type `<ArticleBasePage>` and loop through the collection and render these. I don't like working in the UI I simply want to create a hierarchy of classes(that are pages) just like I would do in Episerver.

Is there any way to do this? Or a guide maybe? I don't like the approach of creating pages in the UI, I want my pages to be of a certain class so I can get the benefits that comes with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umbraco is vastly different from current Episerver versions (7+) in terms of managing the content model, but you can achieve somewhat similar code-first features to enable inheritance.

You may want to have a look at [uSiteBuilder](https://github.com/vegaitsourcing/uSiteBuilder) (available as a NuGet package).

Some more information available on [Jon Jones' blog](http://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-developers-guide/umbraco-packages/how-to-build-an-umbraco-7-document-types-in-visual-studio-usitebuilder-explained).

Comment: Don't use uSiteBuilder if you're in v7+ (or, actually, v4+). Umbraco v7+ has a baked-in ModelsBuilder that generates somewhat strongly typed classes for you.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, I just saw "strongly typed". I've been bitten by uSiteBuilder in the past, so I still wouldn't recommend it as it creates a strong dependency that you can't control or easily replace. I had a couple of sites stuck on v4 for a loooong time because uSiteBuilder didn't work on v6 and it would take forever to remove it from the projects :-s

Comment: You can control where each doctype is "visible", like if you have a NewsOverview doctype you can specify that only NewsItem doctypes can be created under it. If that's what you meant :-)

Comment: @JannikAnker I created a "ArticleBasePage" inheriting from Vega.USiteBuilder.DocumentTypeBase. After that i created a "ArticlePage"(decorated with the [DocumentType] attribute) inheriting from ArticleBasePage. I hoped for a attribute to decorate my ArticleBasePage so that it will not show up in the backoffice under "Document Types" but still show ArticlePage as a document Type.

Comment: Ugh. No idea - is it necessary to have ArticleBasePage inherit from DocumentTypeBase? Through the backoffice you can do "compositions" combining several doctypes into one. And then of course you configure that no one can create documents using the composition doctypes. I haven't worked with uSiteBuilder for ages :-s

Comment: Didn't they include page typing in the latest Umbraco version?